# How long it take for coverity analysis after travis build success?

Tags: static-analysis, coverity

https://github.com/rajeshgopu/coverity_test

It Shows pending from long time in gihub project status.
Does the travis script has issues .or i have to wait to get the result from coverity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not trigeering due to missing "build_command_prepend" in trvis script & indentation in script. Once made as sample project it worked.

Commit link : https://github.com/rajeshgopu/coverity_test/commit/5c373431de93b7b36e75dcf75037f0b947903708